# statistical test for samples that follow normal distribution, with each sample having multiple measurements?

Tags: statistics

I have a set of sample (i = 1 : n), with each one measured for a specific metric 10 times. 
The metric mean of the 10 measurements for each sample has a mean mu(i).

I've done dbscan clustering on all the mu, to find out the outlier samples. Now I want to test whether a given outlier is statistically different from the core samples.

The samples appear to follow normal distribution. For each sample, the 10 measurements also appear to follow normal distribution.

If I just use the mu(i) as the metric for each sample, I can easily calculate Z-score and p-value based on normal distribution. My question is, how do I make use of the 10 measurements for each sample to add to my statistical power (is it possible?)

Not very good at statistics, anything would help, thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about statistics, and not programming.

Comment: I agree this may be more appropriate for Cross Validated (but needs editing). Helen, your question is very confusing. I've ready it a few times and I am still not sure what you are trying to do.